# Case Clause in Select Statements Visual Web Developer

Tags: sql, database, if-statement, case

I'm having some trouble getting the required output.  Currently I have two textboxes that search a database and display the results (SerialNumber and SiteID).  Right now only when both of those boxes are filled, only then is the data displayed.  However what I want is if the Serial Number is blank and Site ID is 3 then all the data with Site ID 3 is played.  If Serial Number is T7 and Site ID is blank then all the data with Serial Number T7 is displayed.  If both fields are empty nothing is displayed.  And lastly if SerialNum is T7 and SiteID is 3 then all the data with T7 and 3 are displayed.

Right Now: When one of the boxes is empty nothing is displayed in the database.

Here is the code I'm using in an .ASPX file using C#.  Can anyone make a suggestion to this code to obtain the required output, I was thinking maybe a CASE clause or an IF, but i'm not sure where I would put it in the code?  Thanks

```
   <%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="Default.aspx.vb"   Inherits="_Default" %>

   <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0    Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

   <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <head runat="server">
   <title></title>
   </head>
   <body>
   <form id="form1" runat="server">
   <div>

    Enter Serial Number:<br />
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" Text="Search" />
    <br />
    <br />
    Enter Site Name:<br />
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
    <br />
    <br />
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server"></asp:Label>
    <br />
    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server"></asp:Label>
    <br />
    <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server"></asp:Label>
    <br />
    <br />
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" 
        AutoGenerateColumns="False" BackColor="White" BorderColor="White" 
        BorderStyle="Ridge" BorderWidth="2px" CellPadding="3" CellSpacing="1" 
        DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" GridLines="None" AllowSorting="True">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="SerialNum" HeaderText="SerialNum" 
                SortExpression="SerialNum" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="SiteId" HeaderText="SiteId" 
                SortExpression="SiteId" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Location" HeaderText="Location" 
                SortExpression="Location" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ContainerId" HeaderText="ContainerId" 
                SortExpression="ContainerId" />
            <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="Misplaced" HeaderText="Misplaced" 
                SortExpression="Misplaced" />
            <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="Frozen" HeaderText="Frozen" 
                SortExpression="Frozen" />
            <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="Scratched" HeaderText="Scratched" 
                SortExpression="Scratched" />
            <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="Destroyed" HeaderText="Destroyed" 
                SortExpression="Destroyed" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ScratchpoolId" HeaderText="ScratchpoolId" 
                SortExpression="ScratchpoolId" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Vendor" HeaderText="Vendor" 
                SortExpression="Vendor" />
            <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="Exported" HeaderText="Exported" 
                SortExpression="Exported" />
            <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="Erased" HeaderText="Erased" 
                SortExpression="Erased" />
            <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="Bad" HeaderText="Bad" SortExpression="Bad" />
            <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="Encrypted" HeaderText="Encrypted" 
                SortExpression="Encrypted" />
            <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="Virtual" HeaderText="Virtual" 
                SortExpression="Virtual" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ReturnDate" HeaderText="ReturnDate" 
                SortExpression="ReturnDate" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ReturnSiteId" HeaderText="ReturnSiteId" 
                SortExpression="ReturnSiteId" />
        </Columns>
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#C6C3C6" ForeColor="Black" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#4A3C8C" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#E7E7FF" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#C6C3C6" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Right" />
        <RowStyle BackColor="#DEDFDE" ForeColor="Black" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#9471DE" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F1F1F1" />
        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#594B9C" />
        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#CAC9C9" />
        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#33276A" />
    </asp:GridView>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:VerticesConnectionString %>" 

        SelectCommand="SELECT SerialNum, SiteId, Location, ContainerId, Misplaced, Frozen, Scratched, Destroyed, ScratchpoolId, Vendor, Exported, Erased, Bad, Encrypted,  Virtual, ReturnDate, ReturnSiteId FROM Media
                    FULL JOIN MediaInfo
                    ON Media.MediaID= MediaInfo.MediaID
                    FULL JOIN MediaStatus
                    ON MediaInfo.MediaID= MediaStatus.MediaID
                    FULL JOIN MediaReturn
                    ON MediaStatus.MediaID= MediaReturn.MediaID
                    FULL JOIN MediaGenT
                    ON Media.NoteID= MediaGenT.NoteID
    WHERE (([SerialNum] like '%' + @SerialNum + '%') AND ([SiteId] = @SiteId))">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="TextBox1" Name="SerialNum"  PropertyName="Text" 
                Type="String" />
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="TextBox2" Name="SiteId"  PropertyName="Text" 
                Type="Int32" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>

</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you have to keep a check upon the arguments in textbox- 
first remove the where condition from main query, append this where condition depending upon the arguments mentioned

```
SelectCommand=SELECT SerialNum, SiteId, Location, ContainerId, Misplaced, Frozen,    Scratched, Destroyed, ScratchpoolId, Vendor, Exported, Erased, Bad, Encrypted,  Virtual, ReturnDate, ReturnSiteId FROM Media
                FULL JOIN MediaInfo
                ON Media.MediaID= MediaInfo.MediaID
                FULL JOIN MediaStatus
                ON MediaInfo.MediaID= MediaStatus.MediaID
                FULL JOIN MediaReturn
                ON MediaStatus.MediaID= MediaReturn.MediaID
                FULL JOIN MediaGenT
                ON Media.NoteID= MediaGenT.NoteID"

if(SerialNumber!=null && SiteID!=null)
{

SelectCommand+="WHERE (([SerialNum] like '%' + @SerialNum + '%') AND ([SiteId] = @SiteId))"
}
elseif(SerialNumber.isnull() && !SiteId.isnull())
{
 SelectCommand+="WHERE  [SiteId] = @SiteId"
}
elseif(!SerialNumber.isnull() && SiteId.isnull())
{
SelectCommand+="where [SerialNum] like '%' + @SerialNum + '%'"
}
```

P.S Please use syntax of your respective language.

Comment: I have actually made a mistake Nirmesh.  I'm not using C#, I'm using Basic.  Can you please make the necessary changes to your answer?

Comment: your problem is in sql query. not other basic code.This is just a pseudocode.. you can try this with any language of your choice. Just check - if  both arguments are present then use "and" in where clause. If only one argument is present then use only that argument in where clause.